# Struct without definition used as pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, struct

I have come across some code that looks like it is forward declaring a struct but I can not find any definition for the struct in the code base. It seems to be used as though the struct was defined. Could someone explain why the below code is valid c++?

What type is Frame? What is the size? I cannot use sizeof() as it will complain it is undefined.

I am trying to convert a similar piece of code to Visual Studio 2015 from 2010. The reinterpret_cast cast is complaining that it cannot be converted due to the fact that

> 'reinterpret_cast': conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'Frame *' of
>   greater size

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Frame;

int main()
{
    unsigned long currentFrame = 5;
    Frame* frame = reinterpret_cast<Frame*>(currentFrame);
    printf("%p", frame);
}
```

GCC 4.9.2 was used to compile this example.

I understand the error, but do not understand how the struct is being used. Is it defaulting to int?

Comment: `struct Frame;` is an incomplete `struct` definiton. That is you can pass around pointers to `Frame` but you cannot dereference pointers to `Frame`. ll that can be said is : _`struct Frame*`  is a pointer to some unknown `struct`_. `conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'Frame *' of greater size` means that `'unsigned long` is smaller than `struct Frame*` as you compile for 64 bits. So the size of `unsigned long` is 32 bits bujt the size of a pointer is 64 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program behaviour is *undefined*, as a conversion from an `unsigned long` to `Frame*` where the former is set to a value not associated with a pointer value that you can set is not in accordance with one of the possibilities mentioned in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast.

The fact that `printf` appears to output the address of a pointer is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

The fact that `Frame` is an *incomplete type* does not matter here. With the exception of `nullptr`, one past the address of a scalar (i.e. single object or a plain-old-data object), and one past the end of an array, the behaviour on setting a pointer type to memory you don't own is also *undefined*.

Comment: Doesn't [expr.add]/4 imply that one pass the address of any single object is also valid, just not dereferencable?

Comment: Is this code safe as long as no one deferences the struct? Or if they import this code in a library header and then implement the frame themselves?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Is I not saying that when I write "one past the address of a scalar" innit?

Comment: @marsh: No it is not safe. You can't set a pointer to memory you don't own, subject to the exceptions I give in my answer. Even `int* p = new int; delete p; int* q = p;` is strictly UB.

Comment: IIRC a scalar is a subset of objects.  AFAIK `std::vector` is not an scalar but you can get a pointer to one past a vector.,

Comment: @NathanOliver: Indeed you can, and `end()` relies on that. Interestingly that's one reason why `rend()` can't be one before the beginning of a vector. That would be a truck load of UB.

Comment: The types do not have to be "related" for `reinterpret_cast` to be usable.  If OP had used `uintptr_t` or `unsigned long long` instead of `unsigned long` then there would not be UB.

Comment: @M.M. Well that's a good point, and I've amended the answer, which is necessarily harder to read. Ta.

Comment: "the behaviour on setting a pointer type to memory you don't own is also undefined." is not true in general either. Common implementations have relaxed pointer safety.

Comment: @M.M. Now *that* one is something on which we are going to talk about. Common implementations allow it indeed (my definition of common being every compiler I've worked with and that's into double digits), but it is formally undefined behaviour: `int* p = new int; delete p; int* q = p;` being my favourite illustration. I'll be downvoted to oblivion if I said otherwise ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba The case you just gave is implementation-defined , C++14 [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/4. However that differs from the case in the question. `delete p;` is specified as rendering `p` invalid (ibid). However casting integer to pointer is not specified as creating an invalid pointer if the implementation has relaxed pointer safety ([basic.stc.dynamic.safety]/4). It is up to the implementation whether to make OP's code defined or not (if he fixes the integer size issue)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Frame` just as a pointer the compiler doesn't need to know anything about `Frame` structure itself. It's like using an opaque pointer to something without caring what's pointed.

The cast fails because `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be the same size of a pointer according to operating system and data model (eg LLP64 vs LP64). You should consider using `intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>` which is guaranteed to be able to store all the bits of a pointer but I don't see how you could need to reinterpred a literal to a memory address.